# Adding popular post feature to Ruby on Rails blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have a blog on my site that has a vist count for each post visited. I used this tutorial as a guide to set it up.

[Railsthink.com](http://www.railsthink.com/articles/3-code-highlighting-with-coderay)

Following the tutorial I was able to get it set up. Now I want to add a feature using the count to list popular posts on the posts/index page.

**schema.rb**

```
    create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
      t.string   "title"
      t.text     "text"
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
      t.text     "description"
      t.string   "cover_image_file_name"
      t.string   "cover_image_content_type"
      t.integer  "cover_image_file_size"
      t.datetime "cover_image_updated_at"
      t.string   "slug"
    end

    add_index "posts", ["slug"], name: "index_posts_on_slug", unique: true, using: :btree

    create_table "visit_details", force: true do |t|
      t.integer  "visit_id"
      t.string   "ip_address", limit: 15
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
    end

    add_index "visit_details", ["ip_address"], name: "index_visit_details_on_ip_address", using: :btree
    add_index "visit_details", ["visit_id"], name: "index_visit_details_on_visit_id", using: :btree

    create_table "visits", force: true do |t|
      t.integer  "visitable_id"
      t.string   "visitable_type", limit: 30
      t.integer  "total_visits"
      t.integer  "unique_visits"
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
    end

    add_index "visits", ["visitable_id"], name: "index_visits_on_visitable_id", using: :btree
    add_index "visits", ["visitable_type"], name: "index_visits_on_visitable_type", using: :btree
```

**post.rb**

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :visit, :as => :visitable
    end
```

**visit.rb**

```
    class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :visitable, :polymorphic => true
      has_many :visit_details

      def self.track(obj, ip_address)
        visit = Visit.find_or_create_by_visitable_id_and_visitable_type(obj.id, obj.class.name)
        ### check if visit is unique
        unless VisitDetail.find_by_visit_id_and_ip_address(visit.id, ip_address)
          visit.increment!(:unique_visits)
        end
        visit.increment!(:total_visits)
        visit_detail = visit.visit_details.create(:ip_address => ip_address)
      end
    end
```

**visit_detail.rb**

```
    class VisitDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :visit
    end
```

Here's where I was trying to add the feature by doing something like this but this doesn't access the Visits table

**posts_controller.rb**

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
      index def
        @popular = Post.order('total_visits DESC').limit(5)
      end
    end
```

Then in my view I was looking to try something like this

**posts/index.html.erb**

```
    <div>
      <h3>Popular Posts:</h3>
      <ul>
        <% @popular.each do |post| %>
          <li><%= post.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks for taking the time to help out.

Comment: What's the error/issue?

Comment: in the post controller @popular causes the view to give this error: **PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "total_visits" does not exist** Im trying to access the Visits table to get the __total_visits__ column for each post.

Comment: This is telling you that your post table does not have a "total_visits" column.  Looking at your code you "total_visits" are stored in visit table. Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thanks for the guide, im learning and this explains what the joins method does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Post.joins(:visit).order('total_visits DESC').limit(5)`